# Audio data is returning empty array

Tags: javascript, web, fft, tensorflow.js, mediaelement

I'm trying to extract the audio data from a video saved localy to run my tensorflow model. The problem is that the frequencyData is always an array full of 128, on StackOverflow i found some things to change and the result was this code:

```
async function predict(){
            const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('{% static 'WebAI/model.json' %}');
        // do prediction

        const audio = document.getElementById('vid2');

        const ctx = new AudioContext();
        var audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        const analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
        audioSrc.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(ctx.destination);

        analyser.fftSize = 2048;
        const frequencyData = new Uint8Array(3367);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

setTimeout(() => {
        analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyData);
        console.log(frequencyData);
        value = tf.tensor([frequencyData]).reshape([-1, 259, 13]);
        const result = model.predict([value]).dataSync();
        alert("Tu puntuación es de " + result[0]);
}, 500);
        }
```

and the html for the video is:

```
<video id="vid2" controls></video>
```

Then I delayed the functión for 10 secs so i'm sure that all the video is loaded but still doesn't work.
My theory is that i'm taking the raw video input so the code doesn't know how to react and gives a null response (or something like that) but i couldn't find how to change that.
(Using const audio = New Audio(document.getElementById('vid2')); gives the exact same problem).
[Here is a picture of how i see the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrmzw.png)

The video is recorded using the code from here: https://gist.github.com/prof3ssorSt3v3/48621be79794a8a3adeed7971786d4d8

The video file is saved on a blob.
The full script for the audio and video is this. Another thing that i tried was changing audio = const audio = new Audio(videoURL);

```js
<script>

        let constraintObj = {
            audio: true,
            video: {
                facingMode: "user",
                width: { min: 480, ideal: 640, max: 1280 },
                height: { min: 360, ideal: 480, max: 720 }
            }
        };
        // width: 640, height: 480  -- preference only
        // facingMode: {exact: "user"}
        // facingMode: "environment"

        //handle older browsers that might implement getUserMedia in some way
        if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
            navigator.mediaDevices = {};
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraintObj) {
                let getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
                if (!getUserMedia) {
                    return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
                }
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraintObj, resolve, reject);
                });
            }
        }else{
            navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
            .then(devices => {
                devices.forEach(device=>{
                    console.log(device.kind.toUpperCase(), device.label);
                    //, device.deviceId
                })
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err.name, err.message);
            })
        }

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintObj)
        .then(function(mediaStreamObj) {
            //connect the media stream to the first video element
            let video = document.querySelector('video');

            video.echoCancellation = "true";
            video.noiseSuppression = "true";
            video.volume = 0;

            if ("srcObject" in video) {
                video.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;
            } else {
                //old version
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStreamObj);
            }

            video.onloadedmetadata = function(ev) {
                //show in the video element what is being captured by the webcam
                video.play();

            };

            //add listeners for saving video/audio
            let start = document.getElementById('btnStart');
            let stop = document.getElementById('btnStop');
            let vidSave = document.getElementById('vid2');
            let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
            let chunks = [];

            start.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
                mediaRecorder.start();
                console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
            })
            stop.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{

                mediaRecorder.stop();
                console.log(mediaRecorder.state);

            });
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
                chunks.push(ev.data);
            }
            mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{


                let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' });
                chunks = [];
                let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                vidSave.src = videoURL;
                async function predict(){
            const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('{% static 'WebAI/model.json' %}');
        // do prediction

        const audio = document.getElementById('vid2');

        const ctx = new AudioContext();
        var audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        const analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
        audioSrc.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(ctx.destination);

        analyser.fftSize = 2048;
        const frequencyData = new Uint8Array(3367);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

setTimeout(() => {
        analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyData);
        console.log(frequencyData);
        value = tf.tensor([frequencyData]).reshape([-1, 259, 13]);
        const result = model.predict([value]).dataSync();
        alert("Tu puntuación es de " + result[0]);
}, 500);
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
                predict();
                }, 500);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err.name, err.message);
        });

        /*********************************
        getUserMedia returns a Promise
        resolve - returns a MediaStream Object
        reject returns one of the following errors
        AbortError - generic unknown cause
        NotAllowedError (SecurityError) - user rejected permissions
        NotFoundError - missing media track
        NotReadableError - user permissions given but hardware/OS error
        OverconstrainedError - constraint video settings preventing
        TypeError - audio: false, video: false
        *********************************/
    </script>
```

```html
<video id="vid1" controls></video>
        <video id="vid2" controls></video>
        <p><button id="btnStart" class="btn btn-outline-success">START RECORDING</button>
        <button id="btnStop" class="btn btn-outline-danger">STOP RECORDING</button></p>
```

Comment: You are actually waiting for 0.5 seconds not 10 seconds. Could you include the output for `frequencyData` and the expected shape for the model? Also I think the `path` to the model is the issue, `'{% static 'WebAI/model.json' %}'`.

Comment: Yes, the 10 seconds was just an over value to be sure now, the expected shape is (null, 13, 259) that's the reason of the reshape and I don't think the loading of the model is an issue because is not giving any red flags and it doesn't do anything in the audio at that moment but I will load it later to be sure.

Comment: Hmm but in the reshape you specify it as `[-1, 259, 13]` and not `[-1, 13, 259]`.

Comment: Yes yes, the -1 let's the model take the value that it needs and the model is predicting ok, the problem that I'm having is that the data taken from the frequencyData is "empty" I don't mean that it has the wrong shape but an array full of 128 values means that the audio is silenced let's say, in other words it isn't able to pass the data (that is what I read I'm not completely sure).

Comment: And the values 13 and 259 are switched because tensorflow wanted it that way I don't understand that part but it worked jajajaja

Comment: Alright then I suppose it is something to do with `AudioContext`.

Comment: Where is hosted the video source? Sounds like a simple crossorigin issue.

Comment: According to the documentation, the `frequencyData` Uint8Array should be the same length as the fftSize. I wonder if it can be related

Comment: @edkeveked no it's not related, only the last 1319 bytes would be `0`, not `128`, and the first 2048 ones should still be correct.

Comment: The video source if you make me guess is saved localy, I used the code from here https://gist.github.com/prof3ssorSt3v3/48621be79794a8a3adeed7971786d4d8 because I don't know a lot about js.

Comment: ... really? Please include your code as an [mcve]. If you are really using the code there as is, then your MediaStream doesn't have any audio (`audio: false`). Also you shouldn't use a MediaElementSource, instead use directly a MediaStreamSource.

Comment: I changed that to true, the audio in the video is working but ok, I'll send the full code of the video

Comment: Well you are not playing that second video, no sounds is produced from there. But why make it so complicated? Why use a MediaRecorder and two videos? You could pass directly the original MediaStream to your AudioContext.

Comment: I though that passing the video saved would be easier, that's why I used the audioURL later, how can I pass directly the media stream in this case?

Comment: Use audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream).

Comment: Thanks for all the time, i solved it.